# Launching maven file - Unable to Run

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to get maven up and running and I got most of the things done (With help). Currently I can use the 'Run' button but I am unable to run the simple program itself. I get the following message:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.057 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-06T11:33:42+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>Lesson01CipherSolution</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

</project>
```

Run/Debug Configuration:
Add New configuration -> Maven -> Locate given project Folder -> Apply/Ok
*Command line: Empty
*Profiles: Empty
*Resolve Workspace artifacts: Unchecked[image]

Is there any simple solution to this? Thanks in advance.

Update: After adding 'deploy' to command line:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------< groupId:Lesson01CipherSolution >-------------------
[INFO] Building Lesson01CipherSolution 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Lesson01CipherSolution ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Lesson01CipherSolution ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Lesson01CipherSolution ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\A\Desktop\S2_Software\1VOP\Lesson 1\Lesson01CipherSolution\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Lesson01CipherSolution ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ Lesson01CipherSolution ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ Lesson01CipherSolution ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ Lesson01CipherSolution ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\A\Desktop\S2_Software\1VOP\Lesson 1\Lesson01CipherSolution\target\Lesson01CipherSolution-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\A\.m2\repository\groupId\Lesson01CipherSolution\1.0-SNAPSHOT\Lesson01CipherSolution-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\A\Desktop\S2_Software\1VOP\Lesson 1\Lesson01CipherSolution\pom.xml to C:\Users\A\.m2\repository\groupId\Lesson01CipherSolution\1.0-SNAPSHOT\Lesson01CipherSolution-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ Lesson01CipherSolution ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.168 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-06T13:58:51+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project Lesson01CipherSolution: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Which task you are trying to execute?

Comment: Can you elaborate on which 'task'?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: Ah. 'mvn deploy' .

Comment: Did you try `mvn install`

Comment: Yes. All but deploy gives "Build Success" - I am unable to launch it like I would on any other java project.

Comment: can you share your Run configuration?

Comment: Do you mean the pom.xml file or the Run/Debug Configuration?

Comment: please share both

Comment: Posted below. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to define which maven goal will be executed you have to specify it in Debug/Run Configuration in Command line section like this:

[image]

In your example you are missing command line argument and this is why you are getting an error:

```
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
```

EDIT:

See [deploy section](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/lifecycle-sect-common-goals.html#lifecycle-sect-deploy-phase) of the maven book.

You need to define a `<repositories>` element in your `settings.xml` (not in your `pom.xml`, that's bad) or a `<distributionManagement>` element in your `pom.xml` like this:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
        <id>corp1</id>
        <name>Corporate Repository</name>
        <url>file:///home/myfolder/.m2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

See this [Isn't maven-deploy-plugin aware of the pom in which I declared it as a build plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45312708/isnt-maven-deploy-plugin-aware-of-the-pom-in-which-i-declared-it-as-a-build-plu) and

[Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy default-deploy on project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37126573/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-deploy-plugin2-7deploy-d)

Comment: Hmm, I tried adding 'deploy' ad a command line argument, but did not solve the problem.  Still getting sets of errors.

Comment: Added to main post.